# AQGridView lag when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm having a lag when scrolling AQGridView. I use grid view for displaying images. There are about 20 on the screen simalatiously. I found that the most time consuming is  `UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:writeFilePath];` It takes about 0.0015 - 0.004s. Is there a way to optimize the grid view ? I saw apps that also display such number of images but have no lag..

edit: I was wrong the lag happens during setting the image. I've tried setting some palceholder - in this case everything was ok..

Comment: You shouldn't be creating images for any kind of table- or grid-based anything.  You should be caching.

Comment: not sure i understood you correct, but my workflow is like: i'm downloading images from web service and store them. Each time 

- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index

is called i'm checking whether the image is stored. In case yes - i'm setting it. If no - i'm asynchronously downloading it. What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: make sure you are not setting layer.shadow on that image